# IE10 doesnot allow indexedDB for saved pages

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10, indexeddb

[This](http://extremecss.com/demos/notepad/) is an demo app of IndexedDB, it works on my IE10 from web.

But if I save it (filename: index.html) and open it, JavaScript dialog pops up because of this code:

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    alert("Sorry!Your browser doesn't support IndexedDB");
}
```

Don't understand why windows.indexedDB remains null.

**EDIT** On firefox and chrome after saving too it works, so the problem is only with IE.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not hosted, indexeddb won't work. The indexeddb is [origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dependencies) dependend, meaning it needs to have an address. Local file system doesn't meet that requirement.

Webapps are a different story, but these apps need to be installed and run inside a sandbox.

Comment: But why only IE is affected? OR I'm missing something?

Comment: Following the specs it shouldn't be possible. But i think it is possible to enable webapps to work

Comment: IE10 does as the spec says are requires a domain to work. FF/Chrome do their domain handling and treat locally-opened files as still having a domain, which in turn makes it work. I'd argue that IE is doing it _more correct_ than the others but it's highly subjective